# Nested JQuery Function Returns 'undefined' or '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, getjson, webservice-client

Hello Friends on StackOverflow:

I am struggling to find what is causing a nested jQuery function to return values of 'undefined' or '[object Object]'. I have commented the location of the first function, which contains the function call. I can see from my research into this subject I am not alone in this perplexing issue. Depending on which bit of code I use inside the nested jQuery function inside the second "getAttributeValue" function I get different results. Stackoverflow helpers can see the various permutations of the code I have been trying, but are commented out for debugging, etc. The 'alert' method returns perfect clear data the way I want it. The others return nothing, 'undefined', or '[object Object]', but never the perfect clear data I want. I have been at this long enough to know I need help.

The data source is a web api / web service providing JSON data.

Here is the code:

```
//# This is the primary function that gathers data from a web api / web service:
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loadData").click(function () {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                var myHTMLDataTable = "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>";
                myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<tr><th>WebId</th><th>Attributes</th><th>Values</th></tr>";
                for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<tr>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1'>" + (data.Items[i].WebId) + "</td>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1'>" + (data.Items[i].Name) + "</td>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1'>"+ getAttributeValue(data.Items[i].WebId) + "</td>"; //~ function call here
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "</tr>";
                }
                myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML = myHTMLDataTable;
            });
        });
    });

    //# This function returns a current value and uom for the target attribute:
    function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
        var theEnvelopePlease = ""; //~ clear the variable
        var atrbUrl = "https://<<The Target Web API Root Address>>";
        var atrbPrefix = "streams/";
        var atrbWebId = attributeWebId;
        var atrbExtension = "/value";
        //~ Concatenate the URL used to make the request
        atrbUrl = atrbUrl + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
        // theEnvelopePlease = $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) { data.Value });
        return $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {

            //return (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
            //alert(data.Value + " " + data.UnitsAbbreviation);
            //theEnvelopePlease = theEnvelopePlease + (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
            (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);

        });
        // return theEnvelopePlease;
    }
```

the JSON data being retrieved by the nested jQuery function looks like this:

```
    {
      "Timestamp": "2015-06-03T22:22:00Z",
      "Value": 89.660293579101563,
      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",
      "Good": true,
      "Questionable": false,
      "Substituted": false
    }
```

Perhaps there is a JQuery expert reviewing this who sees my mistakes easily. Your help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: because it has been requested I want to show what I get when I use console.log:
[image]

UPDATE: Hi @IronFlare: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion with the revised function code as follows:

```
    function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
        var theEnvelopePlease; //~ clear the variable
        var atrbUrl = "https://<<The Target Web API Root Address>>";
        var atrbPrefix = "streams/";
        var atrbWebId = attributeWebId;
        var atrbExtension = "/value";
        //~ Concatonate the URL used to make the request
        atrbUrl = atrbUrl + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
        $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {
            theEnvelopePlease = (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
        });
        return theEnvelopePlease;
    }
```

and the resulting data is 'undefined' (:-c)

=======================================================

Hi @IronFlare and thank you for your suggestion. I modified the function as follows:

```
    function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
        var theEnvelopePlease; //~ clear the variable
        var atrbUrl = "https://<<The Target Web API Root Address>>";
        var atrbPrefix = "streams/";
        var atrbWebId = attributeWebId;
        var atrbExtension = "/value";
        //~ Concatenate the URL used to make the request
        atrbUrl = atrbUrl + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
        $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {
            theEnvelopePlease = (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
            console.log(data);
        });
        return theEnvelopePlease;
    }
```

and here is a view of the results:
[image]

====================================================

UPDATE: For those who are following this thread I have attempted this permutation:

```
    //# Stackoverflow permutation 03:
    function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
        var theEnvelopePlease; //~ clear the variable
        var atrbUrl = "https://<<The Target Web API Root Address>>";
        var atrbPrefix = "streams/";
        var atrbWebId = attributeWebId;
        var atrbExtension = "/value";
        //~ Concatenate the URL used to make the request
        atrbUrl = atrbUrl + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
        theEnvelopePlease = $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {
            console.log(data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
            return (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
        });
        return theEnvelopePlease;
    }
```

and here is a view of the results:
[image]

Comment: can you try putting console.log instead of alert and see what it is printing?

Comment: Hi @Sushil:
Yes  have tried console.log and it aslo reports perfect data.

Comment: With regards to your update: Hmm. Add `console.log(data);` to the `$.getJSON` callback, and add the object that is printed to the console to your question.

Comment: For @IronFlare I am pleased to report I did finally solve the riddle of 'undefined' or '[object Object]' returned values and posted my answer herein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will follow this posting in the future I am pleased to provide the solution I finally found (5 days later). My key mistake centered on jQuery is essentially designed to manipulate existing HTML/DOM elements using CSS Selectors. In other languages such as C# you can procedurally call a function and get back a result and continue the rest of the program. In my previous attempts JQuery continuously returned 'undefined or '[object Object]' no matter what I tried. In this case I found my solution by first building "myHTMLDataTable" and applying a unique "id" attribute to the `<td>` element I wanted to fill with values. So my revised code first builds the table using a for loop, and then populates the target table cell using a second loop that calls the now working function that returns the clear data I was desperately seeking. Here is the working code:

```
    //# Stackoverflow SOLUTION:
    //# This is the primary function that gathers data from a web api / web service:
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loadData").click(function () {
            //~ First Build the data Table:
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                var myHTMLDataTable = "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>";
                myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<tr><th>WebId</th><th>Attributes</th><th>Values</th></tr>";
                for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<tr>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1'>" + (data.Items[i].WebId) + "</td>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1'>" + (data.Items[i].Name) + "</td>";
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "<td class='col-sm-1' id='" + (data.Items[i].WebId) + "'></td>"; //~ The target table cell using the unique 'WebId'
                    myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "</tr>";
                }
                myHTMLDataTable = myHTMLDataTable + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML = myHTMLDataTable;
            });
            //~ Second Populate the target table cell by calling the 'getAttributeValue' function in a second for loop:
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
                    getAttributeValue(data.Items[i].WebId);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    //# This function returns a current value and uom for the target attribute directly into the target cell:
    function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
        var atrbURL = "https://<<The Target Web API Root Address>>";
        var atrbPrefix = "streams/";
        var atrbWebId = attributeWebId;
        var atrbExtension = "/value";
        //~ Concatenate the URL used to make the request
        atrbUrl = atrbURL + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
        $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {
            var myInnerValue = "";
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (key == 'Value') {
                    myInnerValue = myInnerValue + val + " ";
                }
                if (key == 'UnitsAbbreviation') {
                    myInnerValue = myInnerValue + val;
                }
            });
            $("#" + attributeWebId + "").text(myInnerValue);
        });
    }
```

And here is a screenshot of the results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, and the reason why `alert` is working when `return` doesn't, is because `$.getJSON` doesn't pass its callback output to the main function. When this line is executed:

```
(data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
```

It's only running in the context of the callback, so `getAttributeValue` isn't receiving that data. You should be able to fix this by defining an empty variable before running `$.getJSON`, changing that variable to the response you receive, and then returning that variable, which your code shows that you started to do. What you have is very close to being correct. As far as I can tell, all you would need to do is remove the first `return` before `$.getJSON` and uncomment both the line starting with `//theEnvelopePlease =` and the second return statement, `// return theEnvelopePlease;`. That should result in `getAttributeValue` looking something like this:

```
function getAttributeValue(attributeWebId) {
    var theEnvelopePlease;
    ...
    atrbUrl = atrbUrl + atrbPrefix + atrbWebId + atrbExtension;
    $.getJSON(atrbUrl, function (data) {
        theEnvelopePlease = (data.Value) + " " + (data.UnitsAbbreviation);
    });
    return theEnvelopePlease;
}
```

Hope this helps!